# Eclipse building workspace loop when generating class via ant plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-antrun-plugin

We currently have following setup:
We generate `.properties` files containing localization strings and we also generate a java interface that contains `public static final String` properties for each of the translation keys.

The configuration of the `ant-run-plugin`:

```xml
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <ant antfile="src/main/resources/translation_export.xml"
                                    target="run">
                                    <reference torefid="maven.compile.classpath"
                                        refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                                </ant>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

To keep those files up to date with the translation (these are manipulated elsewhere) we setup a life-cycle mapping so that eclipse can execute the ant script with each incremental build.
This causes eclipse to build the workspace endlessly.

EDIT:

My guess is that because the interface is part of the build path it will trigger a build each time

Comment: I guess so too. Each file change or touching a file triggers all project builders again. So make sure that there are file changes only when there are real changes, for example by generating the code outside of the project and then copying only the diff into the project.

Comment: There is the _Maven Workspace Build_ view to debug such an issue. Could you please show what this view shows? What happens when you press the _Suspend_ button (with the pause icon) in this view?

Comment: @howlger I think we will indeed change how we generate the class, we will work with a checksum and only overwrite the file if the checksums don't match.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. You may want to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63607544/6505250), maybe with screenshots of your case.